# Why Device token generating differently when app run in device directly and creating ipa file time?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

While running my app in device, we are getting device token differently, but generating ipa same app and install to same device but we are getting different device tokens.

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Here is the code which we have used:

```
NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken]; 
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
NSString *apnID = [tempStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; 

NSLog(@"tempStr %@", tempStr); 
if(tempStr.length ==0)
{
   // for simulator 
   tempStr = @"123"; 
} 
[standardUserDefaults setObject:tempStr forKey:@"DeviceToken"];
```

Please guide us, what could be the reason behind such behavior.

Comment: If you use development profile which is push notification enabled then it will generate token from 'apple sandbox' which is a testing server and if you use distribution profile then it will generate token from distribution server thus for same device both can vary, depending on profile and server you use.

Comment: But I am used same profile certificates developer certificates in both places

Comment: can you share the code snippet for method didRegisterForRemoteNotification ?

Comment: NSString *tempStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
    NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *apnID = [tempStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

        NSLog(@"tempStr %@", tempStr);
    if(tempStr.length ==0){// for simulator
        tempStr = @"123";
    }
    
    [standardUserDefaults setObject:tempStr forKey:@"DeviceToken"];

Answer (score 1):

From your code snippet it looks like one which you have stored in userDefaults is not getting replaced with fresh value for device token. The one which you getting in device console is correct device token. It is  which is reflecting your `NSLog(@"tempStr %@", tempStr);` and the one which is shown in Xcode run directly is from user 
defaults.
`[standardUserDefaults setObject:tempStr forKey:@"DeviceToken"];` 
**Update**: Generally Device token is formatted like this.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken{
NSLog(@"My token is: %@", deviceToken);
NSString *strDeviceToken=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",deviceToken];
strDeviceToken=[strDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@" "];
strDeviceToken=[strDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@" "];
strDeviceToken=[strDeviceToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
if(strDeviceToken.length ==0){
    // for simulator
    strDeviceToken = @"123";
}
NSUserDefaults *standardUserDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[standardUserDefaults setValue:strDeviceToken forKey:@"DeviceToken"];   }
```

Comment: Update: you can try "set value" method once you have created a key for DeviceToken in user defaults.

Comment: Thank you..but even also same problem

Comment: remove the old build from device and try re-run

Comment: first time run in device directly from Xcode after i delete the app and create archive generating ipa that file running into device this process i did. But i am getting different device token for same device

Comment: NSString *apnID = [tempStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""]; 
have you checked value for this apnID?